# Show Text while mouse over the button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show some text when the mouse is over the `startbtn`. Please see the JS code below:

```
this.startBtn = new Button(this.game, this.world.width / 4, this.world.centerY, 'Play', styles.btnLargeMain)
this.startBtn.onmouseover="HeHe"
this.startBtn.onInputUp.add(this.startGame, this)
this.startBtn.position.x = this.world.width / 2 - logo.width / 2 + this.startBtn.width / 2
this.startBtn.position.y = this.world.centerY + this.startBtn.height / 2
```

the styles.btnLargeMain will link to

```
btnLargeMain: {
    frame: 'yellow',
    sheet: 'ui',
    bitmap: true,
    font: 'kenvector28',
    size: 28,
  },
```

Comment: and hat your issuse? can you show more code (about `this`)

Comment: i cant run this code "this.startBtn.onmouseover="HeHe""

Comment: code above is creating a button and set the button layout, button design in the game, so i want to add a tooltip into the button while mouse hover @לבנימלכה

Comment: What does this relate to? Add more code please. This isn’t enough for us to help you. You need to add more so we can duplicate the issue you are having.

Comment: If you need a tooltip, you can just assign this.startBtn.title = "Hehe"

Comment: @Goran.it i had tried this but cant work

Comment: show more code please... that the only wat we can help you

Comment: @לבנימלכה https://github.com/groupsky/plane-crasher

Comment: It must work, here you have an example and description: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_title.asp